# Loop through all file directory and grab those with length greater than 5

Tags: linux

Beginner linux user here; I am creating a loop that will go through all directory folders and by echoing their name and extracting the total length of the name and echoing this into the console after storing the echo in wc.

How do I add another condition such that if this total length is less than 5 print it out, otherwise pass?

I have tried the following:

```bash
for i in *                 
    do
        if [ -d "$i" ]
            then
           if (echo n "$i" | wc -m < 5)
                then
                    wc
               fi
        fi
    done
```

Prints out the following:

```
zsh: no such file or directory: 5
zsh: no such file or directory: 5
zsh: no such file or directory: 5
zsh: no such file or directory: 5
...
...
```

How to get files inside parent-directory such that I can access subdirectory files given the condition.

```
for i in *
    do
        if [ -d "$i" ]
             if (( $( echo n "$i" | wc -m ) == 76 ))
             then
             find $i
        fi 
    done
```

Prints files in parent directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<` only works for comparisons inside `(( ))`, not in `( )`.
Your version sees `<` as a redirect from a file called `5`.

Try replacing

```
           if (echo n "$i" | wc -m < 5)
```

with:

```
           if (( $( echo n "$i" | wc -m ) < 5 ))
```

The script as a whole probably still won't do what you want, but it should get you past the error.

Comment: Quick question; If i want to get subdirectories echo to the terminal, how can I achieve this given the condition above? For example, I implied another for-do loop after the condition, however, this only prints the files in parent directory. I have updated my answer for some idea.

Comment: From your question the final desired outcome isn't quite clear to me; and I can't see any changes in your answer. @joe_bill.dollar

Comment: If A is the parent directory and all files inside A are named b, b1, b2 ... then the above code only echos A to the terminal. However, I wanted to know how to get the bs

Comment: I won't try to understand the changes between your initial script and the `answer` you incorporated in the question later on, but I'd solve the problem as I understand it like this:  `find -type d | while read dir; do (( $(basename $dir |wc -m ) > 5 )) && echo  $dir; done`  @joe_bill.dollar

Comment: Not working for me, did you test it? Although it looks like `find $i` worked for me instead of the inner loop. However this seems to print the directory also.

Comment: As I said ... I don't quite understand the changes you introduced, @joe_bill.dollar ... my understanding is that you wanted to find all directories whose name is longer than 5 characters initially. You seem to have veered off that track and taken a different direction, which is rarely a good idea - it makes a dog's breakfast of existing answers.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to search all the directories for those with names of five characters or less you can do that with a `find` command. No need for an explicit loop:

```
find -type d \( -name '??????*' -o -print \)
```

Explanation

- `-type d` - only consider items that are directories
- `\( ... \)` - group these together
- `item1 -o item2` - if `item` fails then execute `item2`
- `-name '??????*'` - match names of six characters or more
- `-print` - print the current item name

Putting this together, first of all we match only directories. The next part matches items (directories) that have at least six characters, and if the match fails then prints out the item (directory) name.

Comment: +1.  With GNU awk, this also works:  `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype egrep -regex '^.*/.{1,5}$'`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for i in *
  do
    if [ ${#i} -gt 5 ]; then
        echo $i: ${#i};
    fi;
  done
```

Answer (score 2):

*Note: your title mentions "length greater than", however your code sample uses the less than symbol, `<`. I've assumed the latter here - if you want the former, change `-lt` to `-gt`*

Since you are using zsh, you could do this more directly using its *glob qualifiers*, without the need for an explicit loop at all:

- qualifier `/` to limit the results to directories only
- the `N` (nullglob) qualifier to suppress errors in the case of no matching files
- (optionally) add the `D` qualifier if you want to include hidden directories.
- qualifier `e:cmd:` to return only those files for which `cmd` returns true

where `cmd` is a shell expression that is applied to each matching filename via the `REPLY` variable - for your case you could use the extended test expression `[[ $#REPLY -lt 5 ]]` to test the length `#` of the result without requiring the external `wc` command. So

```
print -rC1 *(/Ne:'[ $#REPLY -lt 5 ]':)
```

---

To make it rescurse through subdirectories, use the `**/*` "globstar" pattern, and remove leading path components from the `REPLY` variable before performing the length comparison:

```
print -rC1 **/*(/Ne:'[ ${#REPLY##*/} -lt 5 ]':)
```

See `man zshexpn` for details.

Answer (score 0):

@tink brilliantly provided the correct code to help me find the solution.

This script works:

```
for i in *
    do
        if [ -d "$i" ]
             if (( $( echo n "$i" | wc -m ) > 75 ))
             then
             echo "$i" 
        fi 
    done
```